# How do I know that the user granted all asked permissions

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

After the user passes this screen, how do I know that the user checked all the boxes?

[image]

Also, I tried disabling [Incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth) to get an error if the user refuses one of the requested scopes, but it seems that Google doesn't return any error.

So I'm stuck. I want to show users errors when they don't check all the requested scopes.
Any help?

Comment: Can you share with us what you have done so far? You can start by providing us with a sample of the code you used in accessing the API so that we may reproduce the issue at hand on our side. At this point, I can only suggest adding a try-and-catch function (assuming that you are using Google Apps Script) to your script for error handling.